# How can i decrease a random percentage with increasing value

Tags: jquery, css, math

maybe i did not pay enough attention in math, but i dont remember how i can solve this.
in jquery i add a randomized clipping path to my images like so:

```
var max=100;
var spread=5;
jQuery.each( $("img"), function( i, val ) {
    $(val).clipPath(
        [
            [Math.floor(Math.random()*spread*10)/10, Math.floor(Math.random()*spread*10)/10], 
            [max-Math.floor(Math.random()*spread*10)/10, Math.floor(Math.random()*spread*10)/10], 
            [max-Math.floor(Math.random()*spread*10)/10, max-Math.floor(Math.random()*spread*10)/10], 
            [Math.floor(Math.random()*spread*10)/10, max-Math.floor(Math.random()*spread*10)/10]
        ],
       {isPercentage:true}
   );   
})
```

this works like a charm, however since the values are in percentage the can become quite extreme with the image getting bigger.
so what can i use to decrease the "spread" with an increasing height/width value? does Math.log help?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would try making the spread a function of the height and width values. Set a benchmark at spread = 5 for images up to ...x... pixels (a known size that you know works well). Then change the size when an image is larger than this known size.

Comment: thanks, that would surely work, however just out of pure interest I'd like to see if there would be a less manual solution :)
so a gradual decrease of spread

Answer (score 0):

Set spread = constant/(height+width) or spread = constant/(height^2+width^2)^0.5